# Update already in Cloud DynamoDB Data Model using NoSQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local, amazon-dynamodb-index

Is it possible to update my already in Cloud created DynamoDB Model from the Workbench?

For instance i'd like in the future to add more fields and more Global indexes, how can I commit this changes from my NoSQL Workbench? The only option I see to commit the changes is to create a new table, if I try to commit using the same Model with the same table I get this error:

```
Could not commit to DynamoDB as table creation failed: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: table_name
```

So can I submit my changes from the NoSQL Workbench and if not what's the work around?

The only [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.Visualizer.Commit.html) I see only references committing a new table, so what's the way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this one?

Comment: Nop @stuart just learned to do it manually. Don't rely on Amazon support, they suck at a point that there is no support.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.